# ExpandConstant functions seems not to work on Windows 7

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I'm trying to use this function in order to translate {app} variable during run-time. It works good on Windows 2008 (64 bit) but does not work on Windows 7 (64bit).

This is the code I use:

```
[Registry]
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};{app}"; Check: ExpandConstant(NeedsAddPath('{app}'))



function NeedsAddPath(Param: string): boolean;
var
  OrigPath: string;
begin
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', 'Path', OrigPath)
  then begin
    Result := True;
    exit;
  end;
  // look for the path with leading and trailing semicolon
  // Pos() returns 0 if not found
  Result := Pos(';' + UpperCase(Param) + ';', ';' + UpperCase(OrigPath) + ';') = 0;  
  if Result = True then
     Result := Pos(';' + UpperCase(Param) + '\;', ';' + UpperCase(OrigPath) + ';') = 0; 
end;
```

Do you know the reason?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Why don't you make a check like `NeedsAddPath` without any parameter. You're passing a known constant, which you can expand inside of your `NeedsAddPath` function in `Code` section and the result will be same. Moreover, you're passing string to the check result since the `ExpandConstant` returns string, not boolean.

Comment: @TLama, the {app} is stated on run-time, since the user can select any app path that he wants. Furthermore, I'm not InnoSetup expert. I'm just trying to avoid writing a path to PATH variable if already exists. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. But I'm still wondering why this works on Windows 2008 and doesn't on Windows 7. You can try the code from my answer, which fixes the result to the `Check` parameter, but if it won't work then I'd suspect something in the registry path. Do you have both OS available for testing at this time ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work correctly on any OS, since you're doing things in the wrong order.  (If you think it did work on Win2008, that simply means that you weren't testing what you thought you were, or interpreted the results incorrectly.)

The main problem with your code is the way you are invoking the Check function:

```
Check: ExpandConstant(NeedsAddPath('{app}'))
```

You are expanding the result of `NeedsAppPath`, when clearly the code inside `NeedsAppPath` is expecting `{app}` to already be expanded when the parameter is passed in.

Change this to:

```
Check: NeedsAppPath(ExpandConstant('{app}'))
```

(In fact the code as you have it above should not even compile, since Check functions are required to return booleans and ExpandConstant does not do so.  So again, you're evidently not testing what you think you are.)

Comment: Hm, I should have try to compile the original code before fixing it (if it doesn't even compile). You're right with the fix, but there's no need to pass just a known constant (moreover, expand it before passing). If you really need to have a parameter that can vary in its value, expand it at the beginning inside of a function to a local variable. But in this case, there's really no need to have a parameter at all. You'll save some CPU instructions :-)

Comment: True, you can do the `ExpandConstant('{app}')` inside of the function instead of passing it as a parameter.  But there's no particular difference in this case.  (It's actually slightly better to keep it as a parameter, in case you might have two such paths you want to test, eg. `{app}\tools1` and `{app}\tools2`; although this is admittedly a contrived example it's not unreasonable in certain scenarios.)

Comment: Also note that it's bad practive to call `ExpandConstants()` on an already expanded string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might be better, however it doesn't explain why wouldn't the original version work. One thing is sure, the original code passes to the [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) parameter string as a result, instead of boolean, what is basically wrong, but it doesn't explain why it works on Windows 2008:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

#define KeyPath "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "{#KeyPath}"; ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};{app}"; Check: NeedsAddPath

[Code]
function NeedsAddPath: Boolean;
var
  AppPath: string;
  OrigPath: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#KeyPath}', 'Path', OrigPath) then
  begin  
    AppPath := ExpandConstant('{app}');
    Result := Pos(';' + UpperCase(AppPath) + ';', ';' + UpperCase(OrigPath) + ';') = 0;  
    if Result then
      Result := Pos(';' + UpperCase(AppPath) + '\;', ';' + UpperCase(OrigPath) + ';') = 0; 
  end;
end;
```